# How to save a CLLocation with Cloudkit JS

Tags: cloudkit, cloudkit-js

I'm using Cloudkit JS to save data to a public database. Its easy to do when the fields are all strings. I'm stuck now trying to figure out how to save data when the field type is a CLLocation. Somehow I need to structure the JavaScript to send both latitude and longitude values.

See the ??? in the code example below;

```
var new record = { recordType: "Thing",
    fields: {   name: { value: "My Name" },
                description:  { value: "My Description" },
                location: { ??? }
    }
};
```

Does anyone know how to take the lat and long coordinates and represent them in the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing it like this:

```
fields: {
    location: { value: { latitude: lat, longitude: lng }, type: "LOCATION" }
}
```

`lat` and `lng` are Doubles, not Strings

Comment: Thank you sir. This works perfectly and the type: “LOCATION” part is optional